# How to add a new property to a list of objects?

Tags: flutter

I have a list of playcard objects and I want to add a new property 'id' to each playcard. The 'id' should be increased by 1 on every playcard. It should be like an index.
The file looks like this:

```
import 'package:memory/models/playcard.dart';

var availablePlaycards = [
  Playcard(front: 'back.png', back: 'sheep.png', flipped: false),
  Playcard(front: 'back.png', back: 'cow.png', flipped: false),
  Playcard(front: 'back.png', back: 'pig.png', flipped: false),
];

final List<Playcard> clonedCards = [...availablePlaycards];
var doubledCards = List<Playcard>.from(availablePlaycards)..addAll(clonedCards)..shuffle();

void addId() {
  for (int i = 0; i < doubledCards.length; i++) {
      doubledCards[i].id = i;
    }
    print(doubledCards);
}
```

I tried to add a method "addId" but I can not call it.
Also I tried to add the for loop outside of the loop, but that gives an error. That could also work.
Playcard.dart looks like this:

```
# models/playcard.dart

class Playcard {
  Playcard({
    required this.front,
    required this.back,
    required this.flipped,
    this.id,
  });

  final String front;
  final String back;
  bool flipped;
  int? id;
}
```

Comment: "I can not call it." Why not?  What happens?  Also note that `[...availablePlayCards]` and `addAll(clonedCards)` will duplicate *references* to the `Playcard` objects, so your `addId()` function will end up mutating each `Playcard` instance twice.  That's probably not what you want.  If you want to perform a deep copy, you will need to provide a method to create a *new* `Playcard` object that explicitly copies its properties.

Answer (score 0):

Change your playcard class like following by making your id value required,

```
class Playcard {
  Playcard({
    required this.front,
    required this.back,
    required this.flipped,
    this.id,
  });

  final String front;
  final String back;
  bool flipped;
  int? id;
}
```

Update your list like following by adding id value to it,

```
    void main() {
  var availablePlaycards = [
      Playcard(front: 'back.png', back: 'sheep.png', flipped: false),
      Playcard(front: 'back.png', back: 'cow.png', flipped: false),
      Playcard(front: 'back.png', back: 'pig.png', flipped: false),
    ];
  
  final List<Playcard> clonedCards = [...availablePlaycards];
  var doubledCards = List<Playcard>.from(availablePlaycards)..addAll(clonedCards)..shuffle();

  for (int i = 0; i < doubledCards.length; i++) {
      doubledCards[i].id = i;
  }
  print(doubledCards);
}
```

Use logic like this and it will solve your problem. You can't create method inside method.

Comment: Yes, that would work, but would not solve the the task.
I want to clone the initial list of cards, so that every card is doubled.
`final List<Playcard> clonedCards = [...availablePlaycards];
var doubledCards = List<Playcard>.from(availablePlaycards)..addAll(clonedCards)..shuffle();`
Then I know how many cards are available and then I can assign an 'id'. May be there is another way.

Comment: @GunnarPolte updated answer